# Trouble ordering blocks in the left navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

Trying to get the right order for a static block in the left hand side navigation of a category page

Everything is pretty standard , I have a left.phtml file with subcategories - and it looks fine.

I added a static block which I want to appear after it - but the static block always appears before it.  I tried the after="-" ,  but I think I am missing something?

```
<catalog_category_view> 
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>            
        <reference name="left">
            <remove name="currency"/>
            <remove name="left.newsletter"/>
            <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
            <block type="cms/block" name="monthly_comp" after="-">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>monthly_competition</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </reference>            
</catalog_category_view>
```

Comment: If you want to add block before all blocks then you should use before="-" to place block above all the added blocks.

Comment: Thanks @hitarth I’m not sure if you read the post..?  I put after=“-“ and it is appearing before the main block . I want the subvategories block ( browse by ) to be first .

Comment: Yes so If you want to put any block after certain block then you can define after=‘block_name’ to place proper! Have u checked like that ?

Comment: What do I put for the block that is already there? It is not a static block - it is the phtml file in navigation > left . I don’t know what name to put , I just assumed if I put after =“-“ then it would be at the end . But it’s not .